# uploading multiple images from a folder in ruby 2.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.3

I am uploading multiple image files to amazon s3 from a single directory using rails 4, aws sdk gem, i was using file.basename method but it uploads only image name, how can i read only image contents to s3 without using paperclip and carrierwave gem?

Comment: Do you mean it's creating an empty file in S3?  What does your code so far look like?

Comment: No to upload images,I have used File.open method to read images and it is solved.